# MySql: Join on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have created a database movie. in this i wanted to select actor name which has not done any movie with the help of the join.
can anyone help me with this problem

[image]

Comment: Please post plain text, not an image, so we can copy/paste it.

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)